# Multiple filtering class for an Eventlistener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a eventlistener based on filtering some class. I have some `<div>` which have `.product-group-5` and from these I need the ones having `.name` 
I have created this and it works

```
jQuery(".product-group-5").click(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).is(".name")) {
    // do something
   }
});
```

Now I need to filter out another class `.another` in this script and am unable to do so
I tried the below-mentioned script but it's not working

```
jQuery(".product-group-5").click(function () {
    let anotherThis = this;
    if (jQuery(this).is(".name ")) {
        if (jQuery(anotherThis).not(".another")) {
            // do something
        }
    }
});
```

html structure is like this

```
<div class="someClass5 name product-group-5 ">I want to watch this click
</div>
<div class="someClass4 name product-group-1 ">not this
</div>
<div class="someClass3 name product-group-5 ">not this
</div>
<div class="someClass5 name product-group-5 another" style="display: block;"> And exclude this
</div>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pure js example in case you need it.

```js
let htmlList = document.querySelectorAll("div.someClass5:not(.another)")
        for(let htmlElement of htmlList){
        htmlElement.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        console.log('click just here')
        })
        }
```

```html
<div class="someClass5 name product-group-5 ">I want to watch this click
    </div>
    <div class="someClass4 name product-group-1 ">not this
    </div>
    <div class="someClass3 name product-group-5 ">not this
    </div>
    <div class="someClass5 name product-group-5 another" style="display: block;"> And exclude this
    </div>
```

Comment: OP says they have more than one. `querySelector` only returns the first found

Comment: @Carlos1232 thank you for replying. I have edited my question to make my scenario more clear.

Comment: @Imraan Oh gotcha, I did another edit in order to keep it in pure js.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is something like:

```js
$('.product-group-5.name').not('.another').click(function(){
   console.log('Clicked id:', this.id);
})
```

```css
.another{margin:2em 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one" class="someClass5 name product-group-5 ">I want to watch this click
</div>
<div id="two" class="someClass5 name product-group-5 another" style="display: block;"> And exclude this
</div>
<div id="three" class="someClass5 name product-group-5 ">I want to watch this click
</div>
```